# Jenkins copy artifacts from another project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I moved a job that does an update function from one project to another. Under the configure option i used the copy artifacts from another project and updated the tab  with the project name from which project it needs to pull files from and hit save. When i run build on the job, it does not pull the files that it needs to from the intended project and the build fails. Am i missing anything on this?

Comment: I am not sure, but you may have to configure the job that creates the artifacts you would like to copy, to allow the other job to copy them.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the second job? Did the last run of the First job produced any artifacts?

Comment: Yes, error is in the second job. The error is as follows:  Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
INFO: Skipping tests recording.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: @Sascha Kolberg - you were right, i had to allow the project to copy the artifacts.